# Why would these classes serialize to a json of "{}"

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im clearly having a very bad day, Ive tried structs and classes, why when I use unitys JsonUtility.ToJson do I only get {} when I know the class is populated with in fact 81 array items.

```
[Serializable]
public struct PuzzleData
{
    public CellData[,] values;
}

[Serializable]
public struct CellData
{
    public int value;
    public bool isFixed;
}
```

So I make it with:

```
var tmp = new PuzzleData();
tmp.values = new CellData[9, 9];
tmp.values[0,0]=1;
<more lines>
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(tmp);
Debug.Log(json);
```

but my json remains, "{}" yet I know the class has data as I also then send it to the game to be populated, and all the data appears as I entered it.  The JsonUtility class says it will work with arrays of a serializable type, well, this is... so..

I know its the array, but Ive used arrays but admittedly I previously only had them as incoming data, but, for the life of me, I cant work out why its not doing the job.  (btw when class the constructor took care of making the cell data values) so the class works fine either way in unity, but just not getting the json bit to work...

Comment: the c# jsonutility I didnt think worked on getters and setters.

Comment: I don't think you can serialize multi-dimensional arrays.  Make it a single-dimension and abstract the multi-dimension bit in code (you know, using stuff like: `index = row * num_columns + column`).

Comment: @trojanfoe that would be highly annoying to have to use.. it seems odd it doesnt mention it doesnt support multi arrays it says it supports arrays..

Comment: There is [evidence](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1485842/serialize-custom-multidimensional-array-from-inspe.html) I am right though :)

Comment: @trojanfoe it seems so, its hard to follow how in 2020 we still cant do something this simple!

Comment: @Cid nope, it is the other way round! From [JSONSerialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) in the section `Supported Types`: `Unity serializes fields only;`!

Comment: @derHugo good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Trojanfoe already mentioned in the comments it is due to the 2D array, which isn't supported by the serializer that `JsonUtility.ToJson` relies on.

And, be it quite obscured, it is actually documented. If you're willing to go down the rabbit hole a little bit:

From the [`JsonUtility.ToJson` docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html) (emphasis mine):

> Internally, this method uses the Unity serializer; **therefore the object you pass in must be supported by the serializer**: it must be a MonoBehaviour, ScriptableObject, or plain class/struct with the Serializable attribute applied. The types of fields that you want to be included must be supported by the serializer; unsupported fields will be ignored, as will private fields, static fields, and fields with the NonSerialized attribute applied.

Now this doesn't mention anything about multidimensional arrays... But if we go to the [docs about the script serializer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html?_ga=2.175619682.1194370569.1584004944-36563132.1568268131) and scroll down a bit to a small note we find the following (emphasis mine):

> Note: Unity **does not support** serialization of multilevel types (**multidimensional arrays**, jagged arrays, and nested container types). If you want to serialize these, you have two options: wrap the nested type in a class or struct, or use serialization callbacks ISerializationCallbackReceiver to perform custom serialization. For more information, see documentation on Custom Serialization.

SuperPig from Unity Technologies confirms this in a [forum post here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/jsonutility-fails-to-convert-2d-arrays-to-json-and-also-from-json.387884/#post-2525006) from Feb 24, 2016, in which thread he also later states

> They're going to come at the same time as the Editor supporting other types - this isn't necessarily "far" in the future, though, as I need to work on the serializer for various other features people want as well (such as Dictionary support).

Sadly enough this hasn't been the case as of yet though.